# In Mockingjay Part 2, what pods were in the book but not in the movie?

Tags: the-hunger-games, adaptation-comparison, mockingjay

In the movie [The Hunger Games: Mockingjay Part 2](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1951266/?ref_=nv_sr_1), some of the defense/ambush pods in the Capital were removed, due to the excessive violence and time consumption. Can anyone specify what type of pods were removed from the movie?

Comment: At first I thought, "you spelled 'parts' wrong", but them I'm like "oh, the _pods_ that the Capital used!" (If you read it as "parts" instead of "pods", it becomes a whole new question!)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**The pods are as follows:**

- **Metal darts**

  > On the fourth morning, Soldier Leeg 2 hits a mislabeled pod. It
  >   doesn’t unleash a swarm of muttation gnats, which the rebels are
  >   prepared for, but shoots out a sunburst of metal darts. One finds her
  >   brain. She’s gone before the medics can reach her. Plutarch promises a
  >   speedy replacement.
  >
  > <sub>—*Mockingjay*</sub>

  This was omitted from the movie, presumably for reasons of gruesomeness.
- **Gunfire**

  > So today, a special block has been set aside for filming. It even has
  >   a couple of active pods on it. One unleashes a spray of gunfire. The
  >   other nets the invader and traps them for either interrogation or
  >   execution, depending on the captors’ preference.
  >
  > <sub>—*Mockingjay*</sub>

  This was included in the movie.
- **Nets**

  I think this was included in the movie. The net pod from the last quote seems to be the same one that got Mitchell shortly thereafter:

  > There’s a loud snap of a trap as the pod triggers. Four cables,
  >   attached to tracks on the buildings, break through the stones,
  >   dragging up the net that encases Mitchell. It makes no sense—how
  >   instantly bloodied he is—until we see the barbs sticking from the wire
  >   that encases him.
  >
  > <sub>—*Mockingjay*</sub>
- **Bomb/black goo**

  > But you can see him suppressing a smile as he’s double-checking the
  >   next pod. Positioning the Holo to find the best light in the smoky
  >   air. Still facing us as his left foot steps back onto the orange
  >   paving stone. Triggering the bomb that blows off his legs.
  >
  > <sub>—*Mockingjay*</sub>

  This was included in the movie, though in the book it is indicated that the black goo was probably a manual trap:

  > “Count on it,” says Castor. “All the streets are covered by
  >   surveillance cameras. I bet they set off the black wave manually when
  >   they saw us taping the propo.”
  >
  > <sub>—*Mockingjay*</sub>
- **Tracker jackers**

  > The wave must have been enormous, with tremendous power behind it, as
  >   it’s affected several blocks that lie ahead. And though I tread with
  >   care, I think my instinct was right about its triggering other pods.
  >   One block is sprinkled with the golden bodies of tracker jackers. They
  >   must have been set free only to succumb to the fumes.
  >
  > <sub>—*Mockingjay*</sub>

  I don’t recall seeing these in the movie.
- **Flesh-eating rats**

  > Empty now, of everything but us. I swing up my bow and blow up the
  >   first pod with an explosive arrow, which kills the nest of
  >   flesh-eating rats inside.
  >
  > <sub>—*Mockingjay*</sub>

  I don’t think this was included, probably for time reasons.
- **Meatgrinder**

  > When everyone’s joined me, I fire into the intersection, and the Meat
  >   Grinder activates. Huge mechanical teeth burst through the street and
  >   chew the tile to dust.
  >
  > <sub>—*Mockingjay*</sub>

  Included in the movie.
- **Golden light**

  > Two of Gale’s arrows already lie useless beside the wide shaft of
  >   golden light that radiates from ceiling to floor. Inside, Messalla is
  >   as still as a statue, poised up on the ball of one foot, head tilted
  >   back, held captive by the beam. I can’t tell if he’s yelling, although
  >   his mouth is stretched wide. We watch, utterly helpless, as the flesh
  >   melts off his body like candle wax.
  >
  > <sub>—*Mockingjay*</sub>

  Included in the movie.
- **Purple light**

  > As we reach the next corner, the entire block ahead of us lights up
  >   with a rich purple glow. We backpedal, hunker down in a stairwell, and
  >   squint into the light. Something’s happening to those illuminated by
  >   it. They’re assaulted by…what? A sound? A wave? A laser? Weapons fall
  >   from their hands, fingers clutch their faces, as blood sprays from all
  >   visible orifices—eyes, noses, mouths, ears. In less than a minute,
  >   everyone’s dead and the glow vanishes.
  >
  > <sub>—*Mockingjay*</sub>

  Omitted from the movie, probably for reasons of gruesomeness.
- **Steam**

  > A pod’s activated ahead of us, releasing a gush of steam that parboils
  >   everyone in its path, leaving the victims intestine-pink and very
  >   dead.
  >
  > <sub>—*Mockingjay*</sub>

  Omitted from the movie, probably for reasons of time/gruesomeness.
- **Trapdoor**

  > We stop, look around for the pod. There’s nothing. Then I feel the
  >   tips of my boots beginning to tilt ever so slightly. “Run!” I cry to
  >   Gale. There’s no time to explain, but in a few seconds the nature of
  >   the pod becomes clear to everyone. A seam has opened up down the
  >   center of the block.
  >
  > <sub>—*Mockingjay*</sub>

  Omitted, probably for reasons of time.

**So the pods that were omitted were: the metal dart pod, the tracker jacker pod, the flesh-eating rat pod, the steam pod, the purple light pod, and the trapdoor pod.**

Comment: +1, good answer. Couldn't have done better myself :-)